# com.itextpdf.commons.exceptions.UnknownProductException: Product pdfCalligraph is unknown. Probably you have to register it

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I have an application using **Itext 7.1.17** and **typography 2.0.9** to generate Arabic pdf files
and I have two xml license files as follows :

**1- itext-core-license.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<license date="*******" issuer="iText Group NV" library="3">
    <licensee expire="*******">
        <name>*******</name>
        <email>*******</email>
        <company>*******</company>
        <version>7.1</version>
        <key>*******</key>
        <licensetype>commercial</licensetype>
        <signature>*******</signature>
    </licensee>
</license>
```

**2- pdfCalligraph-license.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<license date="*********" issuer="iText Group NV" library="3">
    <licensee expire="*********">
        <name>*********</name>
        <email>*********</email>
        <company>*********</company>
        <version>7.1</version>
        <key>*********</key>
        <licensetype>commercial</licensetype>
        <signature>*********</signature>
    </licensee>
    <product deploymenttype="" expire="*********" licensetype="commercial" major="2" name="pdfCalligraph" platform="java">
        <signature>*********</signature>
    </product>
</license>
```

In my java code before working on the pdf, I load the license files as follows :

```
LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(licensePath + itextkeyCoreFile);
LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(licensePath + itextkeyPdfCalligraphFile);
```

The above code works fine on version **7.1.17** but when upgrading to **itext 7.2.4** and **typography 3.0.1**
I get the following exception :

```
com.itextpdf.commons.exceptions.UnknownProductException: Product pdfCalligraph is unknown. Probably you have to register it.
    at com.itextpdf.commons.actions.ProductEventHandler.tryProcessEvent(ProductEventHandler.java:147) ~[commons-7.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.itextpdf.commons.actions.ProductEventHandler.onAcceptedEvent(ProductEventHandler.java:72) ~[commons-7.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.itextpdf.commons.actions.AbstractContextBasedEventHandler.onEvent(AbstractContextBasedEventHandler.java:70) ~[commons-7.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.itextpdf.commons.actions.EventManager.onEvent(EventManager.java:74) ~[commons-7.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.itextpdf.typography.shaping.Shaper.applyOtfScript(Shaper.java:198) ~[typography-3.0.1.jar:?]
    at com.itextpdf.typography.shaping.TypographyApplier.applyOtfScript(TypographyApplier.java:51) ~[typography-3.0.1.jar:?]
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TypographyUtils.applyOtfScript(TypographyUtils.java:122) ~[layout-7.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TextRenderer.applyOtf(TextRenderer.java:815) ~[layout-7.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.LineRenderer.applyOtf(LineRenderer.java:1314) ~[layout-7.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.LineRenderer.layout(LineRenderer.java:176) ~[layout-7.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.ParagraphRenderer.directLayout(ParagraphRenderer.java:237) ~[layout-7.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.ParagraphRenderer.layout(ParagraphRenderer.java:108) ~[layout-7.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.BlockRenderer.layout(BlockRenderer.java:251) ~[layout-7.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableRenderer.layout(TableRenderer.java:592) ~[layout-7.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableRenderer.layout(TableRenderer.java:423) ~[layout-7.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.addChild(RootRenderer.java:141) ~[layout-7.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.createAndAddRendererSubTree(RootElement.java:367) ~[layout-7.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.addElement(RootElement.java:376) ~[layout-7.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.add(RootElement.java:105) ~[layout-7.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.add(Document.java:140) ~[layout-7.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table.flush(Table.java:764) ~[layout-7.2.4.jar:?]
```

**UPDATE:** looking at the following link

https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/installation-guidelines/installing-the-itext-license-key-and-license-key-library-for-java-and-net

I found out that from version 7.2, I have to use **json license file** instead of xml (there should be a guide to convert from xml license format to json license format)
Also I Will have to use **licensing-base** jar instead of **itext-licensekey** jar

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered, iText switched to JSON license keys from iText 7.2 (and the corresponding add-ons). There's no way to convert XML license keys to valid JSON ones, so iText will simply generate new one(s) for you.

Since you have commercial licenses, just log a support request on their [Jira Support Service Desk](https://jira.itextsupport.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/5/).
You are paying for support after all, commercial customers don't need to rely on the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: My support contract was finished that's why I was searching for a solution here